# sql - duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm putting data from website (json) to sql base.
In db i have these rows.

```
ID | PostId | Name | Message
```

Id is auto-increment primary key. 
PostId also has a unique values.
Name and Message are nothing special.

When I run my script / click on the button in form / ... , the program saves all the values into database (lets say there are 25).
Next time I'm going to press the button there will be added 25 more records (all duplicates), and so on...

Is there a way that the program can check through 'PostIds' if the value already exists  before adding it to the db?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not exists(select * from table where PostId =@PostId)
Begin
 //add
End
```

Comment: I read that using `null as [empty]` instead of * in this case is much better for performance as it can use any index without fetching any rowdata.

Comment: @David Mårtensson - if this was the '90s, you would be correct. The optimizer got fixed a *long* time ago to know how to properly deal with `EXISTS(SELECT *` - it knows it doesn't have to retrieve column information.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement, this can also update the duplicate rows if you like and is easier than useing an if statement

Comment: that is only valid in SQL 2008 though

Answer (score 1):

You have many option

Simple one is that you ask Your data base about that `PostId`

```
SELECT count(PostId) FROM Table where PostId = @PostId;
```